# Como executar um método no Spring Boot antes da conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, api, spring-boot, password, event-listener

Bom Dia,

Estou trabalhando num projeto onde minha API antes de estabelecer conexão com o banco de dados, precisa receber de uma API Externa **(Cofre de Senhas)** a senha do banco, a comunicação com essa API Externa eu fiz através do RestTemplate, porém só consegui fazer com que o spring execute o método no final de todo o processo de inicialização através da anotação `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)`, como eu poderia fazer com que o método fosse executado antes da conexão com o banco de dados?

Segue abaixo o método que criei:

```
    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void passwordVault() {
        
        log.info("Initiating communication with password vault API.");
    
        
        String url = MarketStatisticsConstans.URL_COFRE_DE_SENHAS;      
        
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        
        if(!responseEntity.getBody().isEmpty()) log.info("Successfully communicated with password vault, received content.");
        
        PasswordVaultDTO dto = GsonConverter.JsonToPasswordvaultDTO(responseEntity.getBody());
                
        log.info(dto.getContent());
        
    }
```

E além disso é possível parametrizar que esse método seja executado uma vez ao dia?

Answer (score -1):

Olá!

Você pode mudar a ordem de inicialização dos beans no Spring utilizado a anotação

@Primary ou a anotação @Order

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order

Para executar uma vez por dia, vc pode fazer que o servidor mate a aplicação e suba novamente, e assim buscando novamente a senha no banco de senhas ou um job do Spring Scheduling, que vai ser executado todo dia, destruído os beans do  entity management e subindo novamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Marlon, fiz conforme sua orientação e o que eu vi explicando no site que enviou, retirei a anotação `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)` e coloquei `@Bean` e `@Primary` ou `@Order`, o método até executou antes de alguns outros processos, mais já lá na parte final da inicialização. A conexão com o banco de dados foi feita antes da execução do método.